# jQuery how to show/hide Select by Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help with my jquery script.

I have two `select` boxes. When I select one options from firs `select` box the second box should show 3 items from all available options. The script doing it, but also showing me "additional" value at the top of the second `select` box.

Can someone tell me why?

Here is my HMTL code:

```
<select id="viewSelector" style="float: left;">
 <option value="0">-- Select a View --</option>       
 <option value="view1">W</option>
 <option value="view2">X</option>
 <option value="view3">Y</option>
 <option value="view4">Z</option>
</select>

<select id="viewSelect1">

 <option id="view1a">W1</option>
 <option id="view1b">W2</option> 
 <option id="view1c">W3</option>

 <option id="view2a">X1</option>
 <option id="view2b">X2</option> 
 <option id="view2c">X3</option>

 <option id="view3a">Y1</option>
 <option id="view3b">Y2</option> 
 <option id="view3c">Y3</option>

 <option id="view4a">Z1</option>
 <option id="view4b">Z2</option> 
 <option id="view4c">Z3</option>

</select>
```

Here is my jQuery/JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.viewMap = {
    '0' : $([]),
    'view1' : $('#view1a, #view1b, #view1c'),
    'view2' : $('#view2a, #view2b, #view2c'),
    'view3' : $('#view3a, #view3b, #view3c'),
    'view4' : $('#view4a, #view4b, #view4c'),
  };

  $.each($.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); });
    $('#viewSelect1').hide();

  $('#viewSelector').change(function() {
    // hide all
    $.each($.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); });
      $('#viewSelect1').hide();
    // show current
    $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
      $('#viewSelect1').show();
  });
});​
```

The working example you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/Sg8Xf/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple get id of selected value and add attribute selected .

```
var id = $.viewMap[$(this).val()].attr("id");

$('#'+id).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.viewMap = {
    '0' : $([]),
    'view1' : $('#view1a, #view1b, #view1c'),
    'view2' : $('#view2a, #view2b, #view2c'),
    'view3' : $('#view3a, #view3b, #view3c'),
   'view4' : $('#view4a, #view4b, #view4c'),
};

$.each($.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); });
$('#viewSelect1').hide();

$('#viewSelector').change(function() {
// hide all
$.each($.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); });
  $('#viewSelect1').hide();
// show current
$.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
  $('#viewSelect1').show();
  var id = $.viewMap[$(this).val()].attr("id");

  $('#'+id).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** here is a working jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/Sg8Xf/24/)

added

```
<option id="view0">Select</option>
```

to

```
<select id="viewSelect1">
....
</select>
```

modified your object

```
$.viewMap = {
    '0' : $([]),
    'view1' : $('#view1a, #view1b, #view1c'),
    'view2' : $('#view2a, #view2b, #view2c'),
    'view3' : $('#view3a, #view3b, #view3c'),
    'view4' : $('#view4a, #view4b, #view4c'),
    'viewBlank' : $("#view0")
};
```

and added a line

```
// show current
    $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
    $.viewMap['viewBlank'].show();
    $('#viewSelect1').show();
```

Comment: The same problem - When I pick from first box "W" and from the second "W2" and then from the first "X" I have W2 on the second select list - it should reset it and display only "X1, X2, X3" values.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#viewSelect1').show()
```

to

```
$('#viewSelect1')
             .show()
             .find('option:visible:first')  // get the first visible option
             .attr('selected', 'selected'); // set that option as selected
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sg8Xf/16/)**

#### According to comment

```
   $('#viewSelector').change(function() {
        var str = $('#viewSelect1 option:selected').attr('id').replace(/view\d/,'');
        // hide all
        $.each($.viewMap, function() {
            this.hide();
        });
        $('#viewSelect1').hide();
        // show current
        $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
        $('#viewSelect1')
            .show()
            .find('option:visible[id*='+ str+']')
            .attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sg8Xf/26/)**

Comment: it's not workin propertly. When I pick from first box "W" and from the second "W2" and then from the first "X" I have W2 on the second select list - it should reset it and display only "X1, X2, X3" values.